# Vba copy to autofilter

Tags: excel, copy-paste, autofilter, vba

I would like to copy a value (cell content is a vlookup formula) from sheet 1 to sheet 2. And in sheet 2 it needs to be filled in within an autofilter. I recorded the macro but i cannot create a paste special (value only thus) within the "critical".

Now VBA keeps using the "consultancy"-value only and if cell A23 changes (due to the vlookup formula) it does not uses the new value.

Could you please help me out?

```
Range("A23").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Theory").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AR$2653").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
    "Consultancy"
Sheets("Practice").Select
```

Comment: you didn't record `paste special operation`. try to repeat your recording... for criteria you could try something like this: `..., Criteria1:=Sheets("your sheet name here").Range("A23")`

Comment: Excuse me @KazJaw, Sheet 1 = "Theory" and sheet 2 = "Practice" within my code. 

I tried to use your code, which is doing at least something but it gives me no value (only the empty values within the autofilter) eventhough the selected cell (A23) shows the correct information. Im a total newby to VBA solutions...

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer because I do not fully understand the question.
In your question you menton "sheet1" and "sheet2" and "critical" ; in the code these keyword do not appear, so I don't see how to link the code with the explanation.

Regarding the specific point "perform a paste special - value only", this is the way :

```
Range("A23").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Theory").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AR$2653").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= "Consultancy"
Sheets("Practice").Select
```

Comment: @d-dstroyer, thanks for the comment. Sheet 1 = "Theory" and Sheet 2 = "Practice". Nevertheless it does not make sense for me (as a total newbe) where i need to put your code within my code. Could you please help me out on that one? I tried it in a way KazJaw explained but i guess i forgot somewhere, somehow, something

Comment: Ok, I edited to show the context for _PasteSpecial_ command. Does this help you ?